# Getting "_this.fooBar is not a function" when calling local fooBar method from within another local method inside strict export default module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module, this

Here's the StackBlitz example code: [js-m8uxyl](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-m8uxyl).

Here's pasted module with which I have problem:

```
'use strict'

export default {
  isTrue: (val) => {
    return val ? true : false;
  },

  doSquare: (val) => {
    return this.isTrue(val) ? val * val : false;
  },

  doCube: (val) => {
    return this.doSquare(val) * val;
  }
}
```

As you can see, when I'll try to run either `doSquare` or `doCube` method, I get either the following errors: `_this.isTrue is not a function` or `_this.doSquare is not a function`.

How can I properly call the local method from within the other local method?
It really boggles my mind at the moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a combination of how modules and `this` in arrow functions work.

First, the file is an ES6 module and that makes the `this` at the top level of the script a module definition object.

Second, arrow functions (`()=>{}`) inherit the `this` from the scope they are declared in, unlike with the old style `function(){}`, where `this` will be the object it is being declared as a property of. That means that `this` inside the functions is the top level module object, not the exported object.

If they were instead declared using the old-style `function(){}` they should work as expected.

Comment: Yep, it [does work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-5b8knr) like you've said. Thanks!